# TikZ drawing order when using animate

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I've have a problem when I use animations in TikZ images:

I like draw a figure over another figure by

```
\path(fig) node[anchor = north, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=5pt] {
FIGURE1
}

\path(fig) node[anchor = north, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=5pt] {
FIGURE2 over FIGURE1
}
```

This works fine until I use an animation:

```
\path(fig) node[anchor = north, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=5pt] {
\begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay]{2}
  \multiframe{8}{ipic=1+1}{
FIGURE1_\ipic
  }
\end{animateinline}
}

\path(fig) node[anchor = north, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=5pt] {
FIGURE2 over FIGURE1
}
```

The first FIGURE1 is now animated but FIGURE2 is beneath FIGURE1.
Using pgfonlayer/background doesn't help. Does anyone have an idea?

Here is a simple example. In the second frame, the animated background appears, but it should remain beneath the blue block. The only solution I know is to put the "animateinline"-environment around the entire tikz picture, but this is not what I want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) node[anchor = north] {%
BACKGROUND
};

\path (0,0) node[anchor = north,fill=blue] {%
\color{red}HOLLA DIE WALDFEE OVERLAY
};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}


\path (0,0) node[anchor = north,fill=green] {%
\begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay]{2}
  \multiframe{8}{inum=1+1}{
\color{green}\bf BACKGROUND \inum
  }
\end{animateinline}
};

\path (0,0) node[anchor = north,fill=blue] {%
\color{red}HOLLA DIE WALDFEE OVERLAY
};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: I see. You want an animated background and something static in the foreground. But `animate`-generated animations are implemented via PDF annotations (interactive regions). However, PDF annotations don't belong to the page content like normal text/graphics, but live in a separate layer above the page. Thus, they are always in the foreground. Everything you want to appear in front of animated content must itself be part of the animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

By default, `animate`-generated animations are implemented as PDF *Widget* annotations (interactive regions), which live in a separate layer above the normal page content. They are therefore always rendered in the foreground.

The current `[20140923]` version of animate allows using an alternative animation method based on PDF Layers (**OCG** s) whose content is directly embedded in the page content and thus honours the drawing (or *Z*-)order of graphical objects.

Note, that the default Widget-based animation method usually performs better with increasing complexity of the graphics.

Put option `useocg` either as package or command option. It allows for animations placed in the page background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[useocg]{animate}[20140923]
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \path (0,0) node[anchor = north,fill=green] {%
    \begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay]{2}
      \multiframe{8}{inum=1+1}{
        \bf BACKGROUND \inum
      }
    \end{animateinline}
  };

  \path (0,0) node[anchor = north,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.8] {%
    TEXT TO APPEAR IN THE FOREGROUND
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I understand how it works. For the command animategraphics, it would have been very convenient if the ordering would be preserved.

Comment: @Ben: `\animategraphics` behaves similarly, that is, always in the forground.